# Using infix operator in the module in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, functor, infix-operator

I am trying to define a `SCALAR` signature with its own infix operator in

```ml
module type SCALAR =
sig
  type t                               (* type of scalar element *)
       
  val zero : t 
  val one : t

  val (++) : t -> t -> t               (* infix addition: t ++ t *)
end
```

with using `SCALAR` signature, I defined a `INT` module:

```ml
module INT : SCALAR with type t = int
=
struct
  type t = int

  let zero = 0
  let one = 1

  let (++) x y = x + y
end
```

I expected adding two `INT` modules with defined infix operator like `INT.zero ++ INT.one` is valid operation and expected its returning value `int = 1` but it raises error of "Unbounded value ++".

However, `INT.(++) INT.zero INT.one` worked correctly (with the return value I expected).

How can I use specific module's infix operator, without explicitly specifying module's name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use names from a module without mentioning the module, you need to open the module.

Opening modules is something to avoid in many cases. For these cases you can use a local open:

```
# let open INT in zero ++ one;;
- : INT.t = 1
#
```

Another form:

```
# INT.(zero ++ one);;
- : INT.t = 1
#
```

You can also make a local synonym for INT.(++):

```
# let (++) = INT.(++);;
val ( ++ ) : INT.t -> INT.t -> INT.t = <fun>
# INT.zero ++ INT.one;;
- : INT.t = 1
#
```